# Jpa - join different tables depend by column type

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, spring-data

i have a question that i'm not sure its possible with jpa

if i have let say table A

```
public class A {
  Long id;
  Long type;
  Details details; // can this connect to B or c depends on type?
}
```

and table B and C are two different details tables. (not sure anything in common)
can i connect B or C to A depends on `A.type` ?

thanks

Alon

**EDIT**: let me try to be more accurate

i have entity

```
 @Entity     
 @Table(name = "tbl_A")
 public class A implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private Long id; // seems like spring's jpa has issue hanlde "_"

    /*
     *can i achive some thinglike
     *   if  detailsTableType== 1 use Details as B table
     */


     @OneToOne(mappedBy = "details", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
     private B details;

    /*
     *can i achive some thinglike
     *   if  detailsTableType== 2 use Details as C table
     */

     @OneToOne(mappedBy = "details", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
     private C details; //Details

     /*
      * this field set the from where the join should be 
      */

     private Long detailsTableType;

}
```

note the B,C **not** necessarily share anything in common

**EDIT 2:**

one possible solution can be some kind of hack using  getter. which means:
 map in A all the possible join(mark them as lazy) and  create  a getter that will know depend by type which join it should use..

Comment: What you really have here is a class hierarchy with multiple subclasses of `A`.  One type of `A` has a `B` details object, and the other has a `C` details object.  This is like hibernate's combination of Table-per-subclass and table-per-class-hierarchy example.  See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-mixing-tableperclass-tablepersubclass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you want to add some details to A instance with inheriting B and C class from A class.
I recommand you to read documentation about inheritance and discriminator value/column.

On the documentation of [hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#d0e1191) you will see how to
- use the concept of inheritance and TABLE_PER_CLASS strategy
- and describe the descriminator column (your type column)

***Edit :*** but i recommand you to use another strategy like SINGLE_TABLE_PER_CLASS. Note that a JPA provider don't have to support the TABLE_PER_CLASS strategy, and also, this particular startegy have consequences on performance.

**Second Edit : ** Ok : i would suggest you to use polymorphism for B and C class because they use something in common => the link whith the base class A !

You could have :

```
Class A
* Member list of DetailsItf
```

and

```
DetailItf (interface)
 | 
AbstractDetail (SINGLE_TABLE_PER_CLASS strategy with discriminator colum ou TABLE_PER_CLASS) implements DetailItf
 |
 |-B inherits from Details
 |-C inherits from Details
```

Then you have to use an AbstractDetail class in your base A class like :

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@OneToMany( targetEntity=foo.pck.AbstractDetail.class )
private List<DetailsItf> details = new ArrayList<DetailItf>();
```

And on usage, you should make a

```
B myB = new B();
//  saving myB entity
A myA = new A();
myA.addDetails(myB);
// saving myA
```

You should also do specific queriez basing you on TYPE() JPQL specific keywords or, on using FROM CLASS in jpql but you have to create a proof of concept and validate performances.